# Short PHP script works perfectly on one server but not on another

Tags: php, html, json, api

So I've implemented a short PHP script into an html page to determine whether a livestream was online or not. I uploaded it to a free web host and it worked perfectly. I then uploaded it to a paid webhost and the PHP code doesn't work (it shows up the same way it would if I ran it without PHP enabled.) Originally both servers ran the same version of PHP, recently the paid host updated the version of PHP but the problem still persists.

I've run out of ideas to try and fix this, as I'm not the best in PHP. I also contacted the webhost but they were of little help.

Here is the page uploaded to a free host:

http://www.psprod.comli.com/streams.html

And here it is on the paid host:

http://www.somgaming.net/streams.html

The full script is here:

```
<?php
    $chan = "http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=channelname";
    $json = file_get_contents($chan);
    $exist = strpos($json, 'name');
    if($exist) {
        echo "TESTUSER2 - <img src='images/online.png'/>";
    } else {
        echo "TESTUSER2 - <img src='images/offline.png'/>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Does the hosting service enable `allow_url_fopen`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rename your `streams.html` to `streams.php` or make webserver read `.html` as `.php` files.

To make webserver act as you like you need add to your `.htaccess` next lines:

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html .phtml
```

Comment: Renaming the page to streams.php worked perfectly, thank you.